# Access 'ENV' variable in YAML file

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a custom `yaml` file that needs to use an `ENV` variable.

```
YAML.load_file('config/databases.yml')
```

Need to access the PASSWORD variable from the `ENV` variable like the below from the `yaml` file

```
TEST: 
     PASSWORD:  ENV["TEST_DB_PW"]
```

This is not a RAILS app.

How do I do this? `<% ENV["TEST_DB_PW"] %>` works on RAILS but does not work if it is a simple ruby script.

```
require 'yaml'
class Databases
  def initialize
    if File.exist?('config/databases.yml')
      @databases=YAML.load_file('config/databases.yml')
    else
      # You screwed up... 
    end
  end
end

def print_data
 @databases['TEST']['PASSWORD']
end
```

`print_data` needs resolving to the `ENV` parameter referenced in the `YAML` file.

Comment: What are you using other than rails?

Comment: @jhpratt using it in a ruby script. Script loads a YAML file.

Comment: Are you using any libraries? Is this a website? Your question isn't very clear on any of this.

Comment: @jhpratt Updated my post to add clarity.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of the questions I just asked.

Comment: @jhpratt If you look at the code, it uses YAML gem. Thats about it.

Comment: `@database['TEST']['PASSWORD']` should works if your yaml is written as expected. Why not just check what `@database` contains?

Comment: @halfelf thats what i expected. But it just prints the literal value in the YAML file. Does not resolve the ENV

Comment: If so, post your yaml file too. That will give us a verifiable example.

Comment: Do you have your environment variables setup on your terminal? Post your .bashrc or .zshrc as well, to see if the environment variables are properly set.

Comment: @halfelf Look at line 3 code snippet of my post.thx

Comment: @jemonsanto Absolutely. If i just print the ENV variable it works, that is **puts ENV["TEST_DB_PASSWORD"]** works but not **puts @databases['TEST']['PASSWORD']**

Comment: Sorry. I see what you mean now. First check if `ENV["TEST_DB_PW"]` works. If so, test with `eval(@databases['TEST']['PASSWORD'])`, that will evaluate the expression, although I found the yaml may need a little fix about the quote mark. Using single quote around `TEST_DB_PW` should be ok.

Comment: @halfelf thanks. I was looking at the same when you replied. It works with eval.

Comment: Please check [someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  and  [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 15):

> <% ENV["TEST_DB_PW"] %> works on RAILS but does not work if it is a simple ruby script.

`<% ... %>` is an [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) tag. In order to use it, you have to parse the file accordingly.

Assuming you have a file `config/database.yml`:

```
TEST: 
  PASSWORD: <%= ENV["TEST_DB_PW"] %>
```

You can load it via:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'erb'

ENV["TEST_DB_PW"] = "secret"

YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read('config/database.yml')).result)
#=> {"TEST"=>{"PASSWORD"=>"secret"}}
```

Answer (score -5):

This works for me and was confirmed by @halfelf

```
eval(@databases['TEST']['PASSWORD'])
```

if you want to assign it to a variable then

```
password =  eval("#{@databases['TEST']['PASSWORD']}")
```

Comment: Please, do not **EVER** use `eval` in this way. Never.

Comment: @JörgWMittag okay, so what you suggest. Sorry, but i think you gave a -ve remark to my answer, but you never suggested any resolution.